# Ruby web scraping yields two numbers, I only want one

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

```
<span style=\"color: #888888;\"><strike>$44.99</strike></span><br>$15.29
```

I am trying to scrape only the $15.29 via

```
@parse_page.css('.search_results').css('.responsive_search_name_combined').css('.col.search_price_discount_combined.responsive_secondrow').css('.col.search_price.discounted.responsive_secondrow').text
```

but it gives me '$44.99$15.29' instead.
Can anyone tell me how to only get the $15.29 only?
Link for reference : https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=weeklongdeals

Here is the new code, still doesnt work:

> `prices.each do |price|
>     price.children.each do |child|
>       if child.name == 'text' && !child.text.strip.empty?
>         array_price.push(price.text.delete_suffix("                    ").delete_prefix("                        "))
>       end
>     end
>   end`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to scrape only the price $15.29 , you can use a more precise CSS selector or XPath expression to target only the price you want. Here's how you can do it using XPath:

```
require 'nokogiri'

require 'open-uri'

#Fetch the page content

page_content = open('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=weeklongdeals').read

#Parse the HTML

parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML(page_content)

#Extract the price using the provided XPath


price = parse_page.at('//div[contains(@class,""discount_original_price"")]/text()').text.strip

puts price
```

Now you can get $15.29"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution in which the elements that are not wanted are excluded:

```
@parse_page.css('.search_results').css('.responsive_search_name_combined').css('.col.search_price_discount_combined.responsive_secondrow').css('.col.search_price.discounted.responsive_secondrow').each do |element|
  element.children.each do |children|
    # Exclude <span>, <br> and \n
    if children.name == 'text' && !children.text.strip.empty?
      # Print the desired price
      puts children.text
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It does not work, still yields both numbers - here is the new code:prices.each do |price|
  price.children.each do |child|
    if child.name == 'text' && !child.text.strip.empty?
      array_price.push(price.text.delete_suffix("                    ").delete_prefix("                        "))
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just slicing off the other price using

```
array_price[i].slice!(array_discount[i])
```